# How to transition to a modalViewController without stopping the animation while transitioning

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I noticed that if I start a UIView animation on some element of controller "A" and present a controller B with transition, the animation submitted previously doesn't start.
for example:

```
//apply a UIView animation before transitioning
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut             animations:^{
        someUIView.frame = newFrame;
 }completion:nil];
//transition from  controller A to controller B
controllerB.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController: controllerB animated:YES];
```

If the animation has already started and I try to transition to controller B, the animation in A stops. I noticed that this behavior depends on the transition type used. For example, the problem doesn't appear if "UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical" is used.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't start? Probably, you're just missing it! Because if it happens in one, it should happen with the other transition styles too...

Comment: I am sure it doesn't start. And if it has already started, it will stop when the transition starts. Try it out ;) Also turn on "slow animation" in iPhone simulator.

Comment: Hmm...I think I get why it stops. See, in `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`, the master view's layer is untouched. In the other transition styles, a snapshot is taken of the master view's layer and the transition animation is done on that snapshot/layer. So it is happening, but you only see the layer that was created before the animation started. That's how transition animations work so I think this should be the explanation of this anomaly.

Comment: The snapshot doesn't change to reflect the animation that's going on, so we couldn't see it happening.

Comment: @ tipycalFlow this is a very good explanation. This is probably the case. Unfortunately when you use UIview animations to move elements when the keyboard shows/hides while transitioning from one controller to the other, the "frozen" animation doesn't look very good. But I guess there's nothing I can do, except using the transitions that don't take a snaphot (or rasterize) the layer.

Comment: I added a completion block to the UIView animation to check if it completed on time and if it was successful or not, so that i can test if the animation is indeed running on the background. It turns out it doesn't. The "animated" elements take their final values and the completion block runs instantly(since the animation will not show anyway).

Comment: Hmm...we need to dig more into this...try dismissing the modal controller in the completion block and increasing the animation duration to say, 4 sec. If the animation happens, we would see the modal view appearing and then quickly disappearing. Otherwise, it wouldn't appear at all.

Comment: You mean to dismiss the viewcontroller in the completion block of its transition? It will transition in and then out. But the UIView animations on the first controller will not be executed properly.

Comment: Yup...in the completion block...that would reinforce our theory that the animation is happening but we can not see it even though it actually **is happening** in the background.

Comment: The same thing happened. The UiView animations did not run. Their completion handler was called instantly. So the animations didn't run. Th reason they do not run, is what you said earlier. It would be waste of resources if the ran and they didn't show at all

Answer (score 0):

Just present your controllerB from the animation completion block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     someUIView.frame = newFrame;
                }completion:^{
                   //transition from  controller A to controller B
                   controllerB.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                   [self presentModalViewController: controllerB animated:YES];
 }];
```